# Can't open .inf files in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, files, disk

I was trying to play a movie in the Movie Player, but Ubuntu replied with the error that the .inf file that told the disc how to play the movie couldn't be read. Windows is not working right now. Anything I can use to read the file? I have wine installed, in case that can do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I would try vlc. It is in the standard repos and can be installed easily

```
    sudo apt-get install vlc
```

You can get more info from http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html

Comment: Okay. I'll try. I'm at a place where I can overuse and actually lose internet connection if I overuse the Wi-Fi. I'm doing a big download right now.

Comment: Sorry, VLC relies on the .inf files to see what to play when. look at my comment in the second answer for more.

Answer (score 1):

The inf file can't be read because you are using Ubuntu and not Windows. "inf" files are used by the Windows operating system.

You can use any installed Ubuntu media player instead of relying on Wine to play media like movies, DVDs or even music if Wine is not working. You should have AT LEAST one kind of media player with a basic Ubuntu installation. All of them are more capable than Microsoft applications. In Unity, search the apps from the desktop search and the same goes for Gnome. For Xubuntu, Ubuntustudio, and Lubuntu, choose application search to find a media player. For Kubuntu, it's pretty self explanitory.

Comment: I don't use wine to open movies. The movie automatically plays by _using_ the .inf file to start the movie. I can't play it anyway else. I've tried. Movie player won't work and VLC or others won't work. Ubuntu just wont _read_ and _use_ the vital .inf file.